# Scipy odeint ODE error on array sizes

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode

I am trying to solve an ODE which arises from N-body problems in field theory in Physics. For that I thought of using scipy.integrate.odeint function and I have written some code which can be found on:

http://pastebin.com/yuBbEjwg (**updated since the question was first posed**)

However, when I try to execute it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 87, in <module>
    solution = odeint(ODE,XV0,t,args=(M,))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/odepack.py", line 143, in odeint
    ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords)
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

Could somebody point me out what am I doing wrong? And why my code doesn't work? Also, I wanted to ask if there is any difference between using ode and odeint functions in my case?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: corrected silly mistakes (shape() -> shape), thanks to Talonmies for pointing that out. The link above should point to the correct script now.

**EDIT 2**: I somehow suspect that the odeint function doesn't like the tuple returned by the ODE function. Could somebody help on how one formats the tuple if coupled vector ODE need to be solved? I found cases were people are solving coupled ODEs or vector ODEs but not both...

**EDIT 3**: I have reworked the example so that I give odeinit function a matrix of initial conditions and the returned matrix from the function named ODE, is a matrix of the same dimensions... However, I get the same error.

Comment: There are an awful lot of syntax errors in that pastebin code. Clearly you have never even tested your `ODE` function, because if you did, you would have quickly realised that `ndarry.shape` isn't a callable function, it is a tuple, and `ndarray` doesn't have a `dot` method, and more. I would focus on making your code work first before worrying about ODE integration.

Comment: Sorry for stupid mistakes... I was trying to rewrite everything from scratch and I obviously made some mistakes... However, you are wrong on the dot method. If I have t = numpy.array([0,4,3]), then t.dot(t) gives 25, which is expected. The same happens if t = numpy.random.rand(3).

Comment: Actually we are both right on the `ndarray.dot` thing. For a decade, ndarray had no `dot` method (matrix did). It seems like it got added to very recent versions of numpy. Certainly 1.6 and earlier don't have it.

Comment: I don't have time to look deeper, but it seems like you're expecting `odeint` to handle arrays that aren't 1-D. I'm not sure that it does.  IIRC in the past I've had to use wrappers to flatten and then unflatten the data so that it's happy.  [I can't be more confident than that because I haven't used it in a while, and just as happened to @talonmies, something might have changed in the meantime.]

Comment: Thanks talonmies and DSM! I will check it out. Maybe write some wrappers to flatten the arrays before using them... Does anybody now anything about the ode function? can it handle 2D arrays?

Comment: @gns-ank: no it can't. Use `ndarray.flatten()` to get a "vector in-vector out" function that a standard ODE solver can handle.

Comment: FYI: I created a wrapper of `odeint` that handles 2D arrays: https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/odeintw

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser's wrapper works well, thanks!